# Does Cadence Service provide any health check API endpoint

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

Does Cadence Service provide any health check API endpoint to monitor and ensure its availability.

Answer (score 0):

For K8 deployment, I've see this:

```yaml
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 150
            tcpSocket:
              port: rpc
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            tcpSocket:
              port: rpc
```

But it's not http